# How to create a next-page segue between interface controllers programmatically in Apple Watch App?

Tags: watchkit

I am creating a apple watch app and not able to call a next page segue between interface controllers programmatically.

Comment: Is Mike's answer correct?

Answer (score 5):

You are correct that there is no way to programmatically trigger a segue in the current version of WatchKit. The only way to programmatically move to another `WKInterfaceController` in a page-based interface is to call `becomeCurrentPage` on the controller that you want to appear.